# Install .deb package on a Yocto system

Tags: yocto, deb

I have a Yocto system on which I need to install a .deb package. I do understand that some recipes need to be written, however, I am a newbie to this. Can some guide me on what the exact recipe is and/or how to write these recipes

```
root@cs15ka# uname -a Linux cs15ka 3.16.56-yocto-standard #1 SMP
PREEMPT Fri Oct 19 01:35:20 PDT 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: do you want specific binary .deb packages or do you want a specific package? since if you are not tied to specific binary deb then you can use OE to build the package you want and the packages can be searched on layerindex here http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/

Comment: Oh! I am looking for specific .deb package installer recipe

Comment: you might want to look into writing a recipe and `inherit bin_package` also look into bin_package.bbclass as to what its doing, so you can structure the recipe accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to install a .deb package on a Yocto system using opkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403392/failed-to-install-a-deb-package-on-a-yocto-system-using-opkg)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a recipe modeled around something like below, fill in the details for the deb package you want to repackage using OE build system, this will take the .deb file and repackage into what you can then bundle into OE built image. Be aware that there might be binary dependencies that could be incompatible with versions of libraries etc. since the package is built using a different build system and meant for another debian-like OS. So you might have to provide correct versions etc again with additional recipes.

```
inherit bin_package

DESCRIPTION = "..."
LICENSE = "MIT"

PROVIDES = "..."
SRC_URI = " \
https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/${DEB_FILENAME} \
"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "..."

PROVIDES = "..."
RPROVIDES_${PN} = ".."

do_install_append () {
   ... 
}

FILES_${PN} += "..."
```

Comment: Actually, I have a network switch which runs the yocto system. I am trying to install a chef-client package on this switch via a .deb package. On the switch I cannot even access bin_package.bbclass or any other yocto files.

Comment: this instructions are for when you build the package using yocto and your input it deb package, remember that Yocto is a cross build system so it wont happen on your switch but you have to do it on a cross build host like laptop or something. In nutshell you cant mix the packages from diifferent distributiions like this just by installing.